# Discrete Math - Relation among the relations

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-explanation

I need help understanding an assignment involving sets. We're given a few sets,
$A=\{1,2\}$, $B=\{1,2,3\}$, $C=\{1,2,3,4\}$, $P=\{(1,1),(2,3),(3,2)\}$, $Q=\{(1,1),(2,2),(3,2)\}$, $R=\{(1,2),(2,3),(3,2),(3,3)\}$, $S=\{(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,3)\}$ and $T=\{(1,1),(2,1)\}$.

Now, all the questions are just about the same, it's asking which relation among the relations above is a function, for example, from $A$ to $A$. List all. I don't really fully understand what they're asking for/what they expect me to write. I'm also not really knowledgable in sets so if you can give me an explanation it'll be great. Thanks!

Comment: @CameronBuie I think I see it now. So, for example, since A = {1,2} and from A to A that will be {1,2} {1,2} it will create a set of (1,1) (2,2) which is part of Q right?

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't work that way. Have you tried the steps, yet? What have you managed with those?

Answer (score 1):

Well, first, you have to determine which of the given sets (if any) are *relations*. Next, you should figure out which (if any) of those relations are *functions*. After that, you should figure out each function's *domain* and *range*.

**Note**: Each of the italicized words above should be familiar to you, and you will have to know/check the definition of each to answer the questions.

Do your best to complete the steps above (and please show us your thinking on those steps, so we can check your work and gauge your experience level). Once those steps are done, the rest should be straightforward. Let me know if you run into any difficulties.